# Multiple lines lable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the text in my label to be able to flow to the next line if it exceeds the width.
It doesn't seem to do the job now.
Any help is appreciated!!

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
LabelVariable=tk.StringVar()
TextLable=tk.Label(root, textvariable=LabelVariable, justify=tk.LEFT, width=20)
TextLable.pack()
LabelVariable.set("aiea9feafa9fugadioofvaofcoatcefaefcaofcacfaofcoacfa")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an option called [wraplength](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method). You can use that.

> Labels can display multiple lines of text. You can use newlines or use the wraplength option to make the label wrap text by itself. When wrapping text, you might wish to use the anchor and justify options to make things look exactly as you wish.

```
numberOfScreenUnits = 60
TextLable=tk.Label(root, ... , wraplength=numberOfScreenUnits)
```